# Connection between monads and posets?

Tags: category-theory, order-theory

I understand this is broad, but could any elucidate and/or direct me on which structures, areas, and objects to study to get a deep understanding of the relationship between monads and partially ordered sets, especially with regard to relations? Could you provide some formal definitions for these connections, expound upon closure operations over partially ordered sets in the context of monads?

Comment: Monads and partial orders have as much in common as streets and apples. What motivates your question - and what is the *actual* problem which you would like to solve? Do you want to know what monads on partial orders look like and that they are the same as closure operators?

Comment: From Wikipedia, "Monads are used in the theory of pairs of adjoint functors, and they generalize closure operators on partially ordered sets to arbitrary categories." Thus, I'm unsure the streets and apples analogy holds. Could you provide formal definitions for the connections, expound upon closure operations over partially ordered sets in the context of monads?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator#Closure_operators_on_partially_ordered_sets

Comment: Thanks. In that article, the category P is defined implicitly by the "single morphism from x to y", but this is incomplete. Can we been shown the identity and the objects; explicitly define the category P? The relation of the "closure operators" to the monads on the category P isn't clear at all to me as a student. If this were formally stated, it would be extremely helpful and answer my original question almost completely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are referring to the fact that a closure operator is a monad on a poset. http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closure+operator#definition
Note that every poset can be viewed as a category with at most one arrow between each pair of objects. Your question would be better stated as "What is the connection between monads and closure operators?"

Answer (score 6):

One connection is that a pre-ordered set (i.e. a poset minus antisymmetry) can be viewed as a monad in the bicategory $Rel$ http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel